# Not able to figure out why am i not getting the array that i took as input from one thread and trying to print it using another

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond;
void *producer(void *arg);
void *consumer(void *arg);
int buffer[100];
static int n;

void *producer(void *arg) {   //`For taking user input`
int i;
printf("\n Enter the Array of %d terms",n);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
 pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
 scanf(" %d\n",&buffer[i]);

 pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
}

void *consumer(void *arg) {  // For printing the input array
int i;

printf("\nConsumer Function"); 
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{

printf("%d\n",buffer[i]);         
pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}
}

int main()
{
int i=0;
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, 0);
pthread_cond_init(&cond, 0);

pthread_t pThread, cThread;

printf("\n Enter no of terms");
scanf("%d",&n);

pthread_create(&pThread, 0, producer, 0);
pthread_join(pThread,NULL);  
pthread_create(&cThread, 0, consumer,0);   
pthread_join(cThread, NULL);
pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
return 0;
}
```

In the producer function with the help of thread (pThread) I took user input for an array and then I tried to print the same array in the consumer function with the help of cThread. But I am only able to print just the first element of the array. What are the changes that I need to make so that I can get the whole array as output?

Comment: Think about what the [`pthread_join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) function does. You're not running your thread in parallel, it's all done serially.

Comment: One more issue is in consumer thread. Mutex unlock is inside the for loop. It should be outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question is you are doing pthread_join() for a thread before creating new thread. It means, you are exiting the first thread before starting new thread. So all operations are completely serial.

You should start both the threads and then join them as below.

```
pthread_create(&pThread, 0, producer, 0); //Check return value and handle error
pthread_create(&cThread, 0, consumer,0);  //Check return value and handle error  
pthread_join(pThread,NULL);
pthread_join(cThread, NULL);
```

But there is one more issue in you code. In consumer() function you are unlocking mutex inside for loop. I assume, you want user to read one input from user in producer thread and print that input value in consumer thread. In that case you have to move mutex unlock call outside the loop. Please note that, pthread_cond_wait() will internally unlock the mutex during wait. Also, you need to print value after `pthread_cond_wait()` to ensure that user has entered an input value.

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    printf("%d\n",buffer[i]);    
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

**I have written this answer just for the interesting part below!**

Calling pthread_create(); for a thread does not mean that the thread starts running immediately. Multiple threads can run in a random (should be assumed) order.

So.. If consumer thread starts very late i.e. if it starts after two or more `pthread_cond_signal(&cond);` from producer thread, then consumer thread will enter deadlock situation as it does exact n number of `pthread_cond_wait()` calls. Please note that, a `pthread_cond_signal()` is missed if no thread is doing `pthread_cond_wait()` at that exact time instant.

So.. you need to ensure that consumer thread has started before start reading input from producer thread.

There are multiple ways to achieve this. One way is to poll using a global flag and mutex. (You can use another mutex-condition-signal combination for this.)

```
void *producer(void *arg) { 
    while(1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if(1 == consumerStartedFlag) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            break;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        usleep(1000); //Sleep for 1ms to prevent this thread from consuming large CPU
    }

    //Rest of the producer functionality
}


void *consumer(void *arg) {  // For printing the input array

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    consumerStartedFlag = 1; //Global flag, intialize it to zero in main before starting threads.
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    //Rest of the consumer functionality
}
```

Now, if producer starts first, it will wait in `while` loop. If consumer starts first, it will wait in `pthread_cond_wait()`.

**Update 1** Based on a comment below.

In producer(), scanf() is inside mutex lock. It will block the consumer indefinately. So you may not get the output properly. So Put scanf() outside lock as below.

```
 scanf(" %d",&buffer[i]); //Remove '\n' from scanf() as it will block your scanf call.
 pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
 pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Comment: I tried all the things you mentioned but again not able to get the array after the 1st element. Any idea why?   @MayurK

Comment: @DevanshuTripathi I have added an update in my answer for this.

Comment: Still the same after giving the first element of the array it gets stuck and I have to forcefully terminate the program.

Comment: After putting scanf above the lock it's taking only two elements as input for any value of n greater than 2.

Comment: @DevanshuTripathi Remove "\n" in "scanf(" %d\n",&buffer[i]);" --> scanf(" %d",&buffer[i]); Now it is working for me. I have updated it in Update-1.